# Custom menu (Acrobat X) for action using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I created an action using **Action wizard** in Acrobat Pro X.

A JavaScript is running when action started.

**What this Javascript Do?** suppose 100 page in opened pdf, this javascript extract all as seperate pages and rename it as user defined style.

e.g. Hello_001.pdf,Hello_002.pdf,Hello_003.pdf,Hello_004.pdf,... and so on,

i want a **Custom Menu** which target this action to execute.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do, what you've done to try and make it work, and why it isn't working. Could you please edit your question to make theses points more clear? Include any relevant code which showcases your problem as well as any attempts you have made to solve it.

Comment: @MikeC my action is working fine. suppose i named it "ExtractALL" but i want a custom menu which execute this action.

Comment: That does not address anything I said. It sounds like you want to create a custom menu but you have not provided any context, what you have done to try and create it yourself, and why you think it isn't working.

Comment: i use this link [link](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/add_custom_menu_items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you can find your answer in the link you gave. Important is that your script/function works correctly. So test it before in the js console. However here an example, where you can replace the script with yours. Regards, Reinhard

EDIT: (25.11.) Thought can use it by myself, but then I want to have it sortable. So I introduced leading zeros in the extract filename -> function changed.

```
//Save this in the ....\Acrobat\Javascripts\  program or user directory 
//  as whatever.js to load as Add-In

//-> create a submenu as first position under "Edit"
app.addSubMenu({ cName: "Specials", cParent: "Edit", nPos: 0 }); 

//-> now create a Menuitem for the function you will execute
app.addMenuItem({ cName: "Extract all Pages to file", cParent: "Specials", cExec: "extractAll()"}); 

//-> state your function (extract all Pages with leading zeros)
extractAll = app.trustedFunction(function (){
var re = /.*\/|\.pdf$/ig;
    var filename = this.path.replace(re,"");
    var lastPage = this.numPages;
    var lz = Math.pow(10, (lastPage).toString().length); //calc full decimals (10,100,..)
    app.beginPriv(); // Explicitly raise privilege
    for ( var i = 0;  i < lastPage; i++ ) {
        var zPgNo = (lz + i+1).toString().slice(1); //calc actual, cut leading 1 = zerofilled PgNo
        this.extractPages({
            nStart: i,
            nEnd: lastPage -1,
            cPath : filename + "_page_" + zPgNo + ".pdf"
        });
    };
    app.endPriv();
    app.alert("Done!");
})
```

Comment: Great! it works for me very well.. 
I just pasted this code in my Js file and place my Js file here `app.getPath("user","javascript");`. I am amazed why it gives me error of `security level` with my Code while my js is working fine into action.    

function extractAll(){
//-> my code here
}
    app.addMenuItem ({
    cName: " Document Properties", 
    cParent: "Window", 
    cExec: "extractAll()" 
    });

Comment: extractPages is signed as secured ("S") method. So basically it works only in the console or as batch. If you want to use it in a custom menu or elsewhere you have to redesign your function to a trustedFunction. That's what I did. Have a look on the js-help and the given (untrusted) example there. http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/11/Acrobat11_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat11_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.89.471.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger an Action to run from a menu item. However, you can create an application level JavaScript that contains a function that does what you want and then call that function from either an Acrobat Action or a custom Menu Item or both. The answer from [ReFran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022633/refran) shows how to add the custom menu item.